# Array of BufferedImage instances: IIOException

Tags: java, file-io, awt, bufferedimage, ioexception

I'm making a menu, using `awt.Graphics`, and it is giving me a weird `IIOException` when it draws the picture out. Is it due to the program not finding the images? Here is how my code is used.

```
public static BufferedImage[] img;

//this is where img[] gets initialized
for (int j = 0; j < worlds.length; j++) { //say worlds is about 3 or so
    String tmp = worlds.get(j);
    tmp = tmp.replace(".WORLD", "");
    img[j] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\Users\Bryce\Desktop\" + tmp + ".png"));
}


//this is where it gets drawn
for (int i = 0; i < worlds.size(); i++) {
    String tmp = worlds.get(i);
    tmp = tmp.replace(".WORLD", "");
    try {
        for (int j = 0; j < worlds.size(); j++) {
            img[j] = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\Users\Bryce\Desktop\" + tmp + ".png"));
            g.drawImage(img[j], x + 10, y + (ySpace * i), 32, 32, null);
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It keeps giving me the below error message:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've actually realized the silly mistake I made, and it somehow slipped my sight. I forgot to tell how big to make the BufferedImage[]

```
img = new BufferedImage[worlds.size()];
```

It now works!